What's the problem with syntax highlighting?
Any reasons for syntax highlighting not working on main and meta?
(Even when specified explicitly with <!-- language: lang-cpp -->)
// small test
bool this_is_awesome = false;


Code syntax highlighting is a per-site option since there are some sites for which it does not make sense (like movies). Since Bitcoin is a highly technical concept still in its alpha/beta stages and code sharing does occur here with some regularity I've officially petitioned for the option to be set for our site.
